# Why object creator method of factory pattern is accepting string parmeter?

Tags: factory-pattern

Why object creator method of factory pattern is accepting string parmeter?
Why generic creator method is not common?

Comment: It feels like I stumbled into a conversation half-way through. You tagged only [tag:factory-pattern] - it is used in a variety of ways, in a variety of programming languages, through many, many projects, and they definitely don't all accept string parameter. (But why not generic? That's easy: Some languages don't have generics. And if you already know what type you want to create, you can likely just create the object, with no benefit from factory.) I am sure a better answer can be given if you expand your question.